# Let a bool method return other integer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boolean

```
class I {
public:
    virtual bool F() = 0;
};

class A :public I {
public:
    virtual bool F() {
        int i = 2;
        return i;
    }
};

void test() {   
    A a;
    int i=a.F();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

class I is a protocol which is not easy to change.

Want to pass more information than true/false, so want to use the uint8_t property of bool in C++.

But the compiler (VS2019/VS2017) add instructions to convert integer to 0 or 1 at the end of the bool method before return. No converstion on the caller side (only a movzx eax, al instruction) which is good.

Is there a method like a compilation flag or some embedded assembly code at the end of the bool method to let the bool method return an integer other than 0/1?

Comment: If you change the values that the override in `A` can return, then every call site of `F()` needs to be adjusted to handle that change in return value since it may call `F` on an `A`. So effectively you will have to change every use of `F()` anyway, so you can do it cleanly by changing the declared return type in both `A` and `I` with the same amount of work.

Comment: @walnut This is base on a guess that any existing caller use the return value as bool. The guess is highly probable to be true. Can we suppose it to be true for now?

Comment: Depdending on the how the ABI defines passing of `bool` values, the caller may assume that the passed register/stack location is guaranteed to contain only values zero or one. If you violate this guarantee the program may not behave correctly. Have a look at [this recent reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/f2m9vm/whats_the_most_annoying_bug_youve_come_across/fhdrmdz/) describing exactly such a `bool` bug and how hard it is to debug.

Comment: I don't know what the Windows ABI specifically has to say about this, maybe you are lucky and it is technically possible, but I would highly advice against such trickery in any case.

Comment: @walnut Thanks for you alert, will care about this. For now really want to get this done somehow, not a production system. Now the main problem about changing the protocal is: not easy to even find out where to change, and compilation error nightmare may follows. And are you sure changing the protocal won't induce bugs?

Comment: You'd be better off setting a global static or thread_local variable with the extra data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple disclaimer is that this answer is in NO WAY good for production usage. It uses a behaviour which is generally undefined.

You can use `reinterpret_cast` to convert your return value to boolean without actually triggering a `bool` constructor (hence not changing the actual value to 0/1).

```
class A :public I {
public:
    virtual bool F() {
        int i = 2;
        return *reinterpret_cast<bool *>(&i);;
    }
};
```